# Trying to access nested JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to access JSON data that is **nested** quite deep but I can only get so far in the nested JSON, which doesn't seem to be far enough.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{"43993167":{"summonerId":43993167,"pages":[{"id":54725209,"name":"Jinx","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5337}]},{"id":54725210,"name":"support","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5347},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5365}]},{"id":64389802,"name":"Twisted Fate","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5365}]},{"id":69919016,"name":"Ahri","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240898,"name":"Gragas","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240899,"name":"Zac","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5325},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5296},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240900,"name":"Volibear","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5365}]},{"id":71240901,"name":"I AM SMURF GET FKED","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240902,"name":"Graves","current":true,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5335}]},{"id":71240903,"name":"Vi","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5335}]},{"id":71240904,"name":"Reksai","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5335}]}]}}
```

Currently, I can only access up to the slots in each page, but I want to make a variable that will let me determine which slotId in each slot is being used. Heres what I mean:

```
let slotId = slot["runeSlotId"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

 if slotId == "runeSlotId: 1" {

     println(slotId)

 }
}
```

This code however, **does not** work, but that's what I mean when I say I want to make a variable that will let me determine which slotId in each slot is.

Here's my code:

```
 if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary, let include = json.objectForKey("\(self.idNumber)") as? NSDictionary {

                    println("json working")

                    //println(json)

                    if let pages = include["pages"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {


                        println("stat summary working")


                        for page in pages {

                           //println(page)

                            for slot in page {

                                //println(slot)

                                //this is where it determines each slot and where I would like to put the code below but it results in an error

                                /*if let slotId = slot["runeSlotId"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                                    if slotId == "runeSlotId: 1" {

                                        println(slotId)

                                    }
                                }*/
                            }


                            if let name = page["name"] as? String {

                                    //println(name)

                                    self.runeNamesArray.append(name)
                                    //println(self.runeNamesArray)

                            }

                            if let id = page["id"] as? NSNumber {

                               // println(id)



                            }
                        }
```

The data being processed in the code above is the JSON data I provided at the **top**!

If anyone is confused about what I mean, leave a comment and I will edit the post!

Comment: I suggest giving a look at SwiftyJSON when dealing with JSON in Swift: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. I've had a good experience with it.

Comment: I would, but I don't want to use anything third party, I would only like to use Swift's default library.

Comment: It's a single class, one .swift file, and makes dealing with the problems that you're having much easier. I usually avoid reinventing the wheel, especially when it comes to JSON parsing.

Comment: I've already written an insane amount of code based on Swift's JSON, so I don't think I should switch and rewrite it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slotId` is an array of dictionaries, not a String. Maybe once you get slotId, print that before you do any comparison on it to inspect the JSON further. It looks like you're on the right track, but with nested dictionaries, it just takes a little time to understand what type of collection you're looking at at the moment. Break it down in little pieces, or "peel back a layer of the onion at a time", and you'll get it. After you get the array of dictionaries, iterate through each item to see what's in each dictionary, then you can get the value at the key that you need.

Comment: I tried changing it to as? NSDictionary, but it still didn't work :/

Comment: `for slot in page` needs to be `if let slots = page["slots"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]`. You basically need to extract the nested dictionary in that current array element. Then you would say `for slot in slots { ... }`, and get the data for the two elements in each slot by saying `if let runeSlotID = slot["runeSlotID"] as? Int, runeID = slot["runeID"] as? Int { // do something with this information here, such as create a new object with it or whatever }`. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, that does! Thanks so much, I will be sure to comment after this and let you know if it worked, for now, I assume it will, so marking your answer correct!

Comment: Thanks, but yes please do check my answer first to make sure it is what you need. Post back when you find out. Good luck!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! You always know what to do :)